# Ideal c# reduction method for values of the same type, with bitwise approach?

Tags: c#, types, reduction

Good day all,

I have a class and a property, and I have three instances of that class.

```
public class myclass {
  public int myproperty;
}

...

myclass inst1, inst2, inst3;

...
```

Now at a certain point I need to compare those three property values, and verify that they be equal or not, to end up with the least amount of values.

So if I have

```
inst1.myproperty = 3;
inst2.myproperty = 5;
inst3.myproperty = 3;
```

after the magic_function_call, I should get 3 and 5.

And if I have

```
inst1.myproperty = 2;
inst2.myproperty = 2;
inst3.myproperty = 2;
```

after the magic_function_call, I should get 2.

Albeit this is trivial per se, and can be solved with as many IF checks as needed, I was wondering which is the fastest, or more efficient way to do it, especially in light of the fact that I might need to add another variable to the check in the future.

I am in fact wondering if there is a bitwise operation that can be performed that can solve this elegantly and quickly.

Alternatively, is there an array operation that can be used to achieve the same goal? I've tried looking for 'reduction' or 'compression' but those keywords don't seem to lead in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick function which doesn't require any extra libraries and avoids the setup costs and overheads associated with LINQ:

```
    static int[] Reduce(IEnumerable<myclass> items)
    {
        HashSet<int> uniqueValues = new HashSet<int>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            uniqueValues.Add(item.myproperty);
        }

        return uniqueValues.ToArray();
    }
```

Pass it a collection of your myclass instances and it will return an array of unique myproperty values.

Comment: Very nice solution. This looks certainly more versatile than linq in fact.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) `DistinctBy` query operator if all of the instances belong to a collection:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
.. populate list
List<MyClass> distinct = myList.DistinctBy(mc => mc.myproperty).ToList();
```

Looking at the question, you may want a list of just the property values (a list of ints), which you can achieve with the standard query operators:

```
List<int> distinct = myList.Select(mc => mc.myproperty).Distinct().ToList();
```

Note that you haven't defined a property, you've defined a public field. To define an auto property change:

```
public int myproperty;
```

to

```
public int myproperty { get; set; }
```

Note also that PascalCasing is recommended for property and class names.

Comment: Added a minor edit - calling ToList() after the Distinct() call.

Comment: Shouldn't his be `List<int> distinct = myList.Distinct(mc => mc.myproperty);`

Comment: Yes, thank you :) I also realised the Distinct standard query operator doesn't take a key selector, so you could use DistinctBy from morelinq.

Comment: Actually, DistinctBy returns a sequence of TSource, so it would be List<MyClass>

Comment: Thanks for the solution proposal and the clarifications regarding properties. I'll keep the question's original form so that your explanation makes sense.

Comment: Was thinking though, might it be a bit overkill to use linq for this? I mean, is it 'fast enough' compared to the basic 'if' sequence?

Comment: It's almost certainly going to be 'fast enough' (depending on your exact usage), and perhaps more importantly going to produce cleaner code that is easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Just anohter way to implement it .

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(p => p.myproperty).Select(p => p.First());
```